Interpretation of Schmidt coefficients and JSA figure
I'm currently using a python code provided by a fellow PhD student in order to obtain the grating value of a periodically poled crystal (for SPDC process). I must precise this program is under DMCA so I can't share the code in this forum, but I can share the figures I obtained. I'm trying to determine first if the SPDC process is compatible with the wavelength I want to use (pump at 390nm, idler and signal at 780nm), and then what should be the grating. However the figures I obtain are very different depending on the wavelength (in the case of KTP/PPKT, Sellmeier equations are taken from Takaoka et al.).
Here is an example at 1560nm (central wavelength):

And here at my targeted wavelength of 780nm (both Type 0 by the way):

The main issue I have is understanding what is going on. Why are the figures so different and what does it mean?
